# Navigation bar with segment control and custom title view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I create a navigation bar with segment control and custom title view that looks something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that the SegmentedControl only looks like its part of the navigation bar due to coloring. My suggestion here is to implement a custom view with a SegmentedControl and put it just at the top of your ViewController while using the same color for the custom view and the NavigationBar.

For the custom title view you can use the titleView property of the UINavigationItem:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = view // <-- ´view´ is your custom title view
```

See this link and look out for "Customize the Title View":

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar

Comment: Thanks. you were correct! SegmentedControl was seperated from navigation bar! Did the same to achieve it.